# How to clone the object from browser that is opened in remote desktop through automation anywhere?

Tags: remote-desktop, automationanywhere

I am new to Automation Anywhere. My problem is that I want to clone the text field of a website and set text in it. Website is opened in browser of VM that is connected through remote desktop. I am not able to clone that text field using object cloning feature provided by Automation Anywhere.

When I try to clone the text field, object cloning feature selects the whole remote desktop screen rather than that website text field.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to clone any objects in an external machine when your AA instance is installed on another.

With Version 10.x, 11.x, the cloning of objects is only possible when your instance is locally installed.

For your use case, please try with 'Citrix Automation' or an 'Image recognition' to automate kinds of stuff in an external machine.